# Boxplot in R with only median visible

Tags: r, median, boxplot

I want to plot only median for my two dataset. It can be also done using segments function in R but I don't know how. So, I decided using boxplot function but still couldn't figure out how to hide everything and show just medians.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the graphical parameters which are documented under `?bxp`:

```
boxlty: box outline type
whisklty: whisker line type
staplelty: staple (= end of whisker) line type
```

Setting `outline = FALSE` suppresses drawing outliers.

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, outline = FALSE, boxlty = 0,
  whisklty = 0, staplelty = 0)
```

should draw a boxplot with just the horizontal lines at the medians.